# JQuery item not clickable even set click(true)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set a div to be clickable and not clickable. So click(false) is working but click(true) is not working when clicking the div again.

Here is code for disable click

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.target-'+id).click(false);
```

Here is code for enable click.

```
var id = r.parentNode.parentNode.id;
  $('.'+id).click(true);
```

Comment: That is not how click() works.

Comment: Not related to the question, but code like `.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()`  is going to cause you deep regret someday.  Make your code less fragile to DOM changes: use specific classnames or ids, or at least use `.closest('something')` instead of chaining a bunch of `parent()` calls together.

Comment: thanks for advising ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `click(true)`

Instead use: `$('#clickElement').off('click')`.

Comment: @UzzalHosen you should accept the answer if it solved the problem.